# Send form to personal email with an a href link

Tags: forms, href

I'm trying to set up a form with an a href button. I've been changing different things and have submitted the form several times, from 10 I only got 1 email. I know it works, but my question is why does it only work sometimes? here is my code:

```
'<form id="search-form1">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="extra-wrap">
                        <div class="col-1">
                        <label><input type="text"  value="Your full name  (required) " onFocus="if(this.value=='Your full name  (required) '){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your full name  (required) '}" /></label>
                        <label><input type="text"  value="Your email address  (required)" onFocus="if(this.value=='Your email address  (required)'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your email address  (required)'}" /></label>
                        <label><input type="text"  value="Subject" onFocus="if(this.value=='Subject'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Subject'}" /></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <textarea onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your message'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your message' ) this.value=''">Your message</textarea><br>
                            <img src="images/page1-img15.gif" alt="" class="img">
                            <label><input type="text" class="input1"  value="" onFocus="if(this.value==''){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value=''}" />
                                   <a href="mailto:ramon.ramirez0831@gmail.com" class="link8" onclick="document.getElementById('search-form1').submit();return false">Send</a>
                            </label>

                        </div>
                   </div>
                </fieldset>
                    </form>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a server-side script to process the request and send the mail. See **[PHP's mail feature](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php)**.

Comment: thank you, I though I could get away from addin php by just using the a href

Comment: @RamonRamirez: Sure. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the large tick mark under the question's score on the left.